# Compile and link wxGraphicContext with MingW

Tags: c++, mingw, wxwidgets

This is how I compiled GDI+ with wxWidgets

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc USE_XRC=1 SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 BUILD=release UNICODE=1 USE_GDIPLUS=1
```

using those instructions

```
http://www.miscdebris.net/blog/2009/09/17/adding-gdi-headers-to-mingw-to-compile-wxwidgets-with-wxgraphicscontext-support/
```

When I'm trying to compile the application I get this error

```
undefined reference to `wxGraphicsContext::Create(wxWindowDC const&)
undefined reference to `wxGraphicsContext::SetBrush(wxBrush const&)
```

I'm using code blocks on windows as my IDE.

I've been told I need to link against an instance of the wxWidgets library that was compiled with the same flags.

I can't figure out how should I do that,
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The instruction you use are wrong, you also need to edit `include/wx/mse/setup.h` to set `wxUSE_GRAPHICS_CONTEXT` to 1 before building.

They are also out of date (which is more understandable, considering that they're almost 6 years old) and you just need to use a recent MinGW-w64 or TDM-GCC distribution to get GDI+ headers and libraries, there is no need to manually copy anything.